# Android toolbar show end of title

Tags: android

I have an application where the user can go deeper in a structure and would like to show this in the toolbar like 1 > 2 > 3 > 4

but when the toolbar is too long the end gets truncated, how can I do this to the beginning instead so the ending is always showing? I tried searching but could not find anything related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`android:ellipsize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) attribute to change the way text is truncated in a `TextView`; `android:ellipsize="start"` is the value you seem to be looking for.

To do this inside of a `Toolbar`, just replace the title with your own `TextView` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Perfect! Only thing to add is `android:singleLine="true"` otherwise it will start on a new line and not show the dots.

Comment: @Bart Ah, you are right, but `android:singleLine` is deprecated; `android:maxLines="1"` should be used instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: This does not work when used with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` :(

Answer (score 1):

You could change the text size if it reaches a certain length to fit more text. Or you could make your own custom toolbar that allows wrapping of text to multiple lines.